# What is the meaning of abstract in interface

Tags: php

What is the meaning of keyword abstract in interface.
I am trying to write abstract keyword in interface.

```
<?php
interface I
{
     abstract  function test ();
}

class A implements I{
    public function test ($offset)
    {

    }    
}
$x=new A();

?>
```

Getting Error :

```
Fatal error: Access type for interface method I::test() must be omitted in test.php on line 4
```

But here all methods are abstract http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.arrayaccess.php and i have implemented this is working fine.

### What is the reason of error because it is working fine for Predefined Interfaces ArrayAccess

Comment: No need for key `abstract` since all methods defined in interface must be implemented within a class.

Comment: My question is if you open this link http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.arrayaccess.php here is a Interface ArrayAccess where all methods are abstract but i am trying to write own interface method abstract i am getting error

Comment: All methods in interface are already abstract methods. You don't need to implicitly tell every method it is abstract, because it already is by default (I just don't know why there is an error, they could simple ignore that).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interface is an empty class which contains only the declaration of methods.So any
class which implements this interface must contain the declared functions in it. So,
interface is nothing but a strict ruling, which helps to extend any class and strictly
implement all methods defined in interface.

When a method is declared as abstract, it means that the subclass must override that
method. An abstract method should not contain any body where it is defined. An
abstract method can be declared as shown here:
abstract public function test();

If you read carefully above paragraph then you can understand All methods in an interface are abstract.

I think you are confusing becaue abstract keyword is showing before functions.

```
ArrayAccess {
    /* Methods */
    abstract public boolean offsetExists ( mixed $offset )
    abstract public mixed offsetGet ( mixed $offset )
    abstract public void offsetSet ( mixed $offset , mixed $value )
    abstract public void offsetUnset ( mixed $offset )
   }
```

Here abstract is showing function is abstract function.

Answer (score 2):

From php.net
(http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.abstract.php)

"PHP 5 introduces abstract classes and methods. **Classes defined as abstract may not be instantiated, and any class that contains at least one abstract method must also be abstract**. Methods defined as abstract simply declare the method's signature - they cannot define the implementation."

Answer (score 0):

An interface is a definition for a class. It specifies a few methods that are required to exist in order to implement the interface.

An abstract is a combination of an interface and a parent class that you extend. It has a few methods that you have to implement like an interface, but also has a few methods that are defined.

For your code to work, you either need to remove the abstract keyword from the method or change the class definition to be abstract, not an interface. In both cases, you also would need to change the signature of the `test` method to match the definition in the implementing class (add the $offset parameter).